# drupal jquery_countdown module callbacks onExpiry

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

In this module it says:
    *   The onExpiry and onTick arguments is JavaScript that will be passed through "eval()" when the events are called.'

I setup the coundown by passing an array to the theme function thus:

```
'#markup' => theme_jquery_countdown(array(
              'id' => 'timeout-' . $competition_node->nid . '-countdown',
              'options' => array(
                'until' => $time_remaining,
                'format' => 'HMS',
                'compact' => TRUE,
                'onExpiry' => 'Drupal.timedOut',
              ),
```

As markup in a form. 
I have a feeling I need to include a javaScript function called liftOff (this is taken from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) but cant work out what 'passed through "eval()" when the events are called.' means?

Also on the example here (https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) they don't show a themed example with a onExpiry

Answer (score 0):

Include a js file containing.

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.timedOut= function() {
    alert("Do somthing");
    }
}(jQuery));
```